# How Do i Convert I/O Mapping driver to Memory Mapping Driver?

Tags: device-driver

I had written the driver in C for my PCICard where i used I/O Mapping.Now 
i want to use the same driver for PCIEXPRESS card using Memory Mapping.

Can any one Suggest me how to do it?

Comment: What operating system are you targeting?